# Default actions for foreign keys in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

According to the [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions):

> If an action is not explicitly specified, it defaults to "NO ACTION".

How to set defaults to `ON DELETE RESTRICT` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` (I don't want to set this explicit for each foreign keys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change those defaults (if there were such a mechanism, it would be documented).

To get non-default actions, you have to explicitly specify them.

Comment: Dura lex, sed lex. Thank you!